# How to make shell app bar transparent in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, shell, .net-maui

Is there any way to make navigation bar transparent in a .NET MAUI application that uses Shell?

I tried set `Shell.BackgroundColor` to `Colors.Transparent` but it does not work.

Comment: Can you show us how it looks and how you want it to look, with some relevant code?